# convert model.pb to model.tflite

Tags: python, linux, keras, model, tensorflow-lite

i have a ML translation mode build with keras and i have 50 checkoint_epoch.hdf5 and then i found a way to save

the whole mode inside one file which is

```
model.save("model.h5")
```

and then i found a tool i converted this file to the **model.pb** now i have to change it to **model.tflite** in order to use it in mobile app which is **ionic v4 and angular**

and how do i convert the **model.pb** to the **model.tflite**

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert
There is python API and command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the python API.

In TF2.x, to convert your model from a file use:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Further details can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api

In TF1.x, convert your file using:

```
graph_def_file = "/path/model.pb"
input_arrays = ["input"]
# Change the following to your application
output_arrays = ["MobilenetV1/Predictions/Softmax"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

More details here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/python_api.md